# Best way to display menu with items from arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, menu, onclicklistener

I'm creating an Android app which, after all the code, ill get an int array. Let's pretend it's 3, 5,24.
I have 2 other arrays: array1 and array2. I want to know the best way to display a menu like this:

---

### |array1[3]   array2[3] |

### |array1[5]   array2[5] |

### |array1[24]  array2[24]|

---

I need each item to be clickable as well.
How should i do this?

Also, i need to change the background and the letters colour.
thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Do you mean a simple ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple ListView for you

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // create list1 and list2 here
        Integer[] list1 = new Integer[4];
        Integer[] list2 = new Integer[4];

        ListView view = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.root);
        view.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, list1, list2));
    }

    private static class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer>
    {
        public ListAdapter(MainActivity screen, Integer[] list1, Integer[] list2) 
        {
            super(screen, R.layout.listviewrow, list1);
            this.list1 = list1;
            this.list2 = list2;
            this.activity = screen; // << sorry I forgot this!
        }

        public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) 
        {   
            row = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewrow, parent, false);

            TextView view1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item1);
            view1.setText(list1[position] + "");
            TextView view2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item2);
            view2.setText(list2[position] + "");

            return row;
        }

        private MainActivity activity;
        private Integer list1[];
        private Integer list2[];
    }
}
```

Here is the listviewrow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and finally the activity_main.xml:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

If you want to use something besides Integer it should be pretty easy for you to figure out. Just change the generics and change the types around and you should be fine. If you need any more help getting this solution to work let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the info but i'm gettin a null pointer on this line:
row = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewrow, parent, false);
I think the problem is that activity is not initialized. I'll try to solve it, just wanted to leave the info.
I'll give news soon

Comment: @PedroGodinho see my update, I forgot to assign the screen reference in the constructor, sorry!!!